# how to use looping script to upload our produk at online shop site,

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, imacros

I am a new user of  [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) on my Firefox browser to make my work more easy.

How to change this script to looping mode?

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.bukalapak.com/p/fashion/wanita/dress/t6gzs-jual-dress-maggie
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/products ATTR=NAME:product[name] CONTENT=Dress<SP>Jessel
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Wanita
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:/products ATTR=NAME:radio-suggestion
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:+
CONTENT=C:\Users\ziian\Desktop\tos\6-10\14-25\14.1.jpg
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:product_images_upload[data] CONTENT=C:\Users\ziian\Desktop\tos\6-10\14-25\14.jpg
TAG POS=7 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/products ATTR=NAME:product[product_detail_attributes][ukuran][] CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/products ATTR=NAME:product[weight] CONTENT=350
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/products ATTR=NAME:product[stock] CONTENT=100
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/products ATTR=NAME:product[price] CONTENT=58000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ACTION:/products CONTENT=Dress<SP>Jessel<BR>Pilihan<SP>Warna<SP>:<SP>Maroon<SP>&ATTR=NAME:product[description_bb] <SP>Blue<BR>Bhn<SP>Jersey<BR>Allsz<SP>Fit<SP>L
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/products ATTR=NAME:commit
```

Comment: I removed usefulness phrases and corrected the grammar, linked to the plugin iMacros

Comment: Just set the 'Max:' value to a desired number of loops and play this macro in loop mode by means of the 'Play (Loop)' button on the 'iMacros' sidebar.

Comment: Thanks All,, i have found some script it working,